# Equality operator with multiple values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators, equality, inequality

Is there a simple way to compare multiple values to a single value in Javascript ?

Like, instead of writing :

```
if (k != 2 && k != 3 && k!= 7 && k!12)
```

Writing something like :

```
if (k != {2,3,7,12})
```

Comment: `if (![2,3,7,12].includes(k))`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `includes` instead of multiple equality comparisons.

```
if (![2,3,7,12].includes(k))
```

That's boolean algebra:

```
if (k != 2 && k != 3 && k!= 7 && k != 12)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (!(k == 2 || k == 3 || k == 7 || k == 12))
```

and that's equivalent to

```
if (![2,3,7,12].includes(k))
```